# How to use join and where in one clause using eloquent model in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Im just new with laravel and Im having trouble in joining tables with condition.

I have 3 tables.

```
    Table 1 : users
        $users->increments('id');
        $users->string('name');
        $users->string('email')->unique();
        $users->string('password');
        $users->rememberToken();
        $users->timestamps();

    Table 2 : articles
        $articles->increments('id');
        $articles->string('title');
        $articles->string('content');
        $articles->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $articles->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

    Table 3 : Follows
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('blogger_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps(); 

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('blogger_id')
            ->references('user_id')->on('articles')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Here's what happen when a user create an article it will save to the articles table including his user ID. And as a user I can follow him. When I follow him my user id and his user ID will be saved in follows table as user_id and blogger_id respectively.

What I want to happen is when I logged in the articles of the bloggers I follow will show on my home page. Here's what I tried but I having an error.

```
    on my Follow Model :
       class Follow extends Model
        {
            function follows(){
             return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
           }
         }

     on my homeController:
         $current_user = Auth::user();
         $followings = \App\Follow::where('user_id',$current_user->id);
         $result = $followings->follows();
```

This gives me an error : Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::follows does not exist.

I tried to search for the answers I was confused with the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use relationships for joins like that.

First, you have to change your relationship:

```php
class Follow extends Model
{
    function follows(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article', 'user_id', 'blogger_id');
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```php
$followings = \App\Follow::where('user_id', $current_user->id)->with('follows')->get();
$articles = $followings->pluck('follows')->collapse();
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't give me error anymore but it only retrieves the last entry being made by the blogger that I follow.